# Runtime error, input string in array

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error

This is the input strings and the code that is supposed to read the file. When I compile using the lastest Dev C++ at home, it runs perfectly. But the Dev C++ at my school crashes the program (and after debug I know it is) at i = 9. Which is this line `Michael Nguyen 71 70 91 93 28`.

I fixed it by changing `char studentFirst[15]` to `char studentFirst[17]`. However the name that is supposed to be put in `Michael` and `Nguyen` aren't more than 14 char each. Could someone help me take a look at it. Did I understand something wrong this line `fscanf(inFile, "%s%s", studentFirst, studentLast)`?

**Input:**

```
Sidra Amartey 90 88 70 74 70
Rebecca Brown 85 98 73 78 74
Leslie Carter 92 73 86 36 87
Ashley Guillen 95 26 90 83 85
Ryan Hilliard 75 66 69 100 52
Dawn Hopkins 84 69 66 88 74
Kyle Jiwani 7 99 96 84 89
Melvin Johnson 73 80 63 38 88
Edward Maun 82 85 72 75 99
Angelo Morrison 95 97 80 31 70
Michael Nguyen 71 70 91 93 28
Zack Nutt 82 85 97 74 98
Diana Patel 77 70 88 68 82
Patrick Perez 87 77 21 88 7
Abigail Peterson 64 81 75 85 70
Jennifer Putnam 39 91 85 80 70
Kimberly Sanjel 64 69 74 97 12
Marisa Santos 63 77 90 15 60
Hannah Shrestha 13 77 95 97 99
Linda Stoll 50 85 72 91 23
Victoria Taylor 95 93 74 63 90
Haily Wright 80 90 99 68 84
```

**Code:**

```
int loadStudentNamesGrades(studentnode students[], const char * fileName)
{
    FILE * inFile;
    char studentFirst[15] = {0};
    char studentLast[15] = {0};
    int numStudents = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if((inFile = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot access file %s\n", fileName);
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS && (fscanf(inFile, "%s%s", studentFirst, studentLast) == 2); i++, numStudents++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &students[i].grades[j]);
        }
        students[i].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(studentFirst) + strlen(studentLast) + 2);
        strcpy(students[i].name, strcat(strcat(studentFirst, " "), studentLast));
    }

    return numStudents;
}
```

Comment: need  more than 15 for `strcat(strcat(studentFirst, " "), studentLast)`

Comment: So there is a option in my compiler at home helps fixing this.. Thank you BLUEPIXY, very perceptive of you!. I screwed up big time... I want my compiler at home to not autofix this type of problem. This is an unacceptable error.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't "fix" it. What you have is undefined behaviour. UB means that there is no guarantee that any specific behaviour will occur. So not producing an error is perfectly valid and you can't blame the compiler in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is undefined behavior. First you forget to count the terminating `\0`, so `Michael Nguyen` is actually 15 chars, not 14. However your crash is the result of the previous line there `Angelo Morrison` is 16 long, more than `studentFirst` can hold! And `Abigail Peterson` is 17 long, so `studentFirst` needs to be 17 long. `studentLast` only needs to be 9, but that is not a problem.
It does not appear that you have understood fscanf wrong. You might not understand that strcat uses `studentFirst` to hold the full name.